# Json reader in android

Tags: android, json

I want to store(dynamically in runtime) some Json data like name,date of birth,email and phone number of multiple persons. For that a txt file is used and saved it in sdcard.
Also I want to show them in a Listview.

**For that what is the method of creating JsonObject and saving it to file.**

i implemented  one method and on retrieving only i get one object and then Json reader exits the while loop.

My code snippet

---

Creating jsonobject and saving

---

`

```
        File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),             "testfile.txt");
        outputStream = new PrintStream (new FileOutputStream (mFile));


        JSONObject friend = new JSONObject ();


        friend.put("Name", "qwe");
        friend.put("Dob", "21-03-91");
        outputStream.print (friend.toString ());

        friend.put("Name", "fgg");
        friend.put("Dob", "02-05-91");
        outputStream.print (friend.toString ());

        friend.put("Name", "jhg");
        friend.put("Dob", "30-01-91");
        outputStream.print (friend.toString ());
```

`

Retrieving to listview

---

`

```
    String friends = null;
    ArrayList<String> friendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "testfile.txt");

    String text=null;
    if(file.exists())   // check if file exist
    {
        //Read text from file
        text = new String();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text+=line;
                //text+=',';
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader (new StringReader (text));
    try {


        reader.beginObject ();

        while (reader.hasNext ()) {
            reader.nextName();
            friends = reader.nextString().toUpperCase()+" ";
            reader.nextName();
            friends+=reader.nextString();
            friendlist.add(friends);
            friends=null;
        } 
        reader.endObject();
        reader.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, friendlist); 

    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);`
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. I really suggest using SQLIte and CursorAdapter instead

Comment: if data is store temporary use JavaBeen with Arraylist to save or sqlite Data to staore data if sdcord format when data has gone

Comment: you can use Gson to parse Json into Objects

Comment: why json reader exiting after one object

Answer (score 1):

The result in the file will be invalid JSON. It will look like:

```
{
    "Namea": "qwe",
    "Dob": "21-03-91"
}
{
    "Namea": "wsx",
    "Dob": "21-03-91"
}
{
    "Namea": "qtdfddfwe",
    "Dob": "21-03-91"
}
```

You have to serialize the root JSON element and not the individual JSON elements.
Try:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

friend1.put("Name", "qwe");
friend1.put("Dob", "21-03-91");
jsonArray.put(friend1);
jsonArray.put(friend2);
jsonArray.put(friend3);
outputStream.print (jsonArray.toString ());
```

With this approach don't forget to add the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to your androidManifest.xml.

However I would recommend using a sqlite database to store the data.

Comment: If i have 4 key,value pairs under friend1 and it is added to jsonArray. Then when it is retrieved, order is not getting correct

Comment: Strange. The output  My output is: [{"Name":"qwe1","Dob":"21-03-91"},{"Name":"qwe2","Dob":"21-03-92"},{"Name":"qwe3","Dob":"21-03-93"}] .

Comment: Try converting a Java List to a JSONAray.       List<JSONObject> list = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();
            list.add(friend1);
            list.add(friend2);
            list.add(friend3);
            System.out.println(new JSONArray(list).toString());'

Comment: Then also same. unordered